# Python Remove duplicates within 180 days

Tags: python

I have a dataframe as shown below (i.e. df). I want to remove duplicated names if the date is within 180 days of the preceding record. Desired result in dfa

Appreciate advice. Thanks.

**Data I have**

```
import pandas as pd
 
dict = {'Name':['John','John','John','John','John','John','Peter','Peter','Luke','Luke'],'Date':['2021-03-01', '2021-08-01','2021-12-01', '2022-04-11', '2022-10-01','2023-12-01','2021-05-01','2021-12-31','2021-08-01','2021-11-01']}
       
df=pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

**Desired result**

```
dict_answer = {'Name':['John','John','John','John','Peter','Peter','Luke'],'Date':['2021-03-01','2021-12-01', '2022-10-01','2023-12-01','2021-05-01','2021-12-31','2021-08-01']}
 
dfa=pd.DataFrame(dict_answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would have been more useful if you provided more detail of what you want and what you have tried so far.

```
from datetime import datetime

dictionary = {'Name': ['John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'Peter', 'Peter', 'Luke', 'Luke'],
              'Date': ['2021-03-01', '2021-08-01', '2021-12-01', '2022-04-11', '2022-10-01', '2023-12-01', '2021-05-01',
                       '2021-12-31', '2021-08-01', '2021-11-01']}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

```
names = dictionary['Name']
dates = dictionary['Date']

dict_answer = {'Name': [], 'Date': []}

while names:
    if names[0] not in dict_answer['Name']:
        dict_answer['Name'].append(names[0])
        names.pop(0)

        dict_answer['Date'].append(dates[0])
        dates.pop(0)
        continue
    elif names[0] == dict_answer['Name'][-1]:
        d1 = datetime.strptime(dict_answer['Date'][-1], "%Y-%m-%d")
        d2 = datetime.strptime(dates[0], "%Y-%m-%d")
        delta = d2 - d1
        if delta.days > 180:
            dict_answer['Name'].append(names[0])
            names.pop(0)

            dict_answer['Date'].append(dates[0])
            dates.pop(0)
            continue
        else:
            names.pop(0)
            dates.pop(0)

dfa = pd.DataFrame(dict_answer)
```

This best matches the information you have given, and give the output you were looking for.